# Não estou conseguindo executar está linha de comando devido a um erro no php mas n sei qual!

Tags: php, html, css, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Erro que aparece:
*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\developed\rs_alpinismo\salva_mensagem.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\developed\rs_alpinismo\salva_mensagem.php on line 5*

Código que fiz para mandar os dados ao mysql(phpmyadmin) servidor local:

primeiro code:
conexao.php:

```
<?php 
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "areadecontatos";

    // Criar a conexão
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);


?>
```

Second code salva_mensagem.php:

```
<?php 

    include_once('conexao.php');

    $name = $_POST('nome');
    $email = $_POST('email');
    $menssagem = $_POST('menssagem');

   $msg_contato = "INSERT INTO mensages_contato(nome, email, menssage) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$email', NOW())";
   $resultado_msg_contato = mysqli_query($conn, $resultado_msg_contato)
    
?>
```

Action do codigo html:

Estou querendo mandar para o banco de dados local, os seguintes dados

> Nome
> Email
> Menssagem

identificação no formulário de cada uma:

```
name="nome"
name="email"
name="menssagem"
```

Se alguém poder ajudar agradeço!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Nessa linha do arquivo salva_mensagem.php:

$msg_contato = "INSERT INTO mensages_contato(nome, email, menssage) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$email', NOW())";

O correto tem que ser a passagem das variáveis no SQL, você colocou $nome ao invés de $name:

$msg_contato = "INSERT INTO mensages_contato(nome, email, menssage) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$email', NOW())";

Essa linha é a 5, é só você interpretar a mensagem de erro (a linha 5 desse do arquivo corresponde a: $name = $_POST('nome');).

Answer (score 0):

Também é necessário corrigir a última váriavel pra `$menssagem`, no seu código está `$email` duas vezes

```
$msg_contato = "INSERT INTO mensages_contato(nome, email, menssage) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$menssagem', NOW())";
```